# rig armature not working properly

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I had a recent same project I was doing here , but I'm gonna get to the point here , I tried To rig my character as everything works fine , when I move the head , the does not move with the head , it just stand or bugged inside the head , as I'm figuring out how I can manage to do it , everything are joined together[image]

blend [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate meshes (like here eyes and cheeks) often get not correctly parented, to fix that you can select them in *Edit* mode and assign to the head bone (called *spine.006*):

[image]

That said it won't be perfect because you have 2 bones for the neck that influence the head so the eyes and cheeks won't correctly stick at a certain rotation angle of *spine.006*, if you don't need these bones you should remove them, parent *spine.006* to *spine.003*, reparent the mesh to the armature.